# Преобразовать массив хешей в хеши без массива и перезаписи

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Задаю переменной hash массив хешей:

`[12] pry(main)> hash = {:sku=>"1234", :name=>"Test"}, {:sku=>"5678", :name=>"Test2"}`
`=> [{:sku=>"1234", :name=>"Test"}, {:sku=>"5678", :name=>"Test2"}]`

Но при использовании данных в цикле получаю ошибку "TypeError: can't cast Hash".

Вопрос: как преобразовать массив хешей в хеши без массива и перезаписи?

Чтобы переменная hash соответствовала следующему:
`{:sku=>"1234", :name=>"Test"}, {:sku=>"5678", :name=>"Test2"}`

Comment: А добавьте к вопросу тот цикл, в котором вы получаете ошибку, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ты хочешь вынуть из массива хэши и сохранить в переменной как указано?

```
{:sku=>"1234", :name=>"Test"}, {:sku=>"5678", :name=>"Test2"}
```

Это невозможно, потому что в результате получается группа хэшей, которая не может существовать сама по себе. Чтобы работать с этими хэшами как c одним объектом (например, обойти в цикле и изменить значения), нужно поместить их в контейнер или объединить в один хэш, но тут тупик: вкладывать их в контейнер бессмысленно, потому что они уже там судя по твоему вопросу — в том самом массиве из которого ты пытаешься их вытащить, а объединить их в хэш нельзя, потому что у хэша ключи всегда уникальны и в результате объединения ты потеряешь значения.

Обычно такой клинч говорит о том, что ты пытаешься решить какую-то проблему неправильным путем. Тебе нужно более подробно объяснить, какую задачу ты пытаешься решить таким способом, а еще лучше показать код.